# obtaining the info in Matlab's workspace window \ workspace panel

Tags: matlab

I would like to document each time I run a specific script that I have, in particular a list of variables and their values.

Matlab has the function `who` for obtaining the variables name, and `whos` to get more info, but what I really want is just to save the info that I already have in the "workspace panel" that is visible on the screen, where the names and values of various variables are written (sometimes it's actually the value, sometimes the size and class are mentioned). just type `workspace` at the command prompt, if you don't understand what I mean.

I know I can just save the entire workspace as a .mat file (and I do so), but I just want a small txt file with that info so I wont need to load matlab to see what's in that file.

Is there a simple way you are aware of that allows to access that info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add on @il_raffa answer, maybe another solution to display variable values just like they appear in workspace browser is to use `workspacefunc('getshortvalue', eval(varname))` instead of direct call to `eval(varname)`:

```
v = whos();
for idx = 1:length(v)
    name = v(idx).name;
    value = workspacefunc('getshortvalue', eval(name));
    fprintf(1, '%s\t\t\t\t\t\t%s\n', name, value); 
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `diary` command to save the information on a .txt file:

**Updated answer**

You can use the output of `whos` whitin a loop which uses `eval` to display the value of the variable and store it in the diary file.

**Updated code**

```
clear all

a=peaks;
b=magic(4);
c=size(b);
d=length(a);
v_str.n=1

diary('w.txt')
whos
zzz=whos;
for i=1:length(zzz)
   eval([zzz(i).name])
end
diary off
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: that's nice,  but the question was to obtain the names and values of the workspace window. `whos` has the option to be used as `h=whos` and all it;s info is there *but* the values... still +1 on `diary` .

Comment: I've updated the code, so it should also save the variable values in the log file.